# Tcl test script execution does not end

Tags: linux, testing, tcl, selenium-chromedriver

I have five files as described below:

### run_tests.tcl

```
package require tcltest
namespace import ::tcltest::*

if {$argc!=0} {
    foreach {flag param} $::argv {
        if {[string match -* $flag]} {
            configure $flag $param
        }\
        else {
            $flag $param
        }
    }
}
runAllTests
```

### add.test

```
package require tcltest
namespace import ::tcltest::*
source add.tcl

test add1 {} -body {
    add 1 1
} -result 2

cleanupTests
```

### add.tcl

```
proc add {a b} {
    return [expr $a+$b]
}
```

### sample.test

```
package require tcltest
namespace import ::tcltest::*
source sample.tcl
test google_search {} -body {
    search
} -result 1

cleanupTests
```

### sample.tcl

```
package require selenium::chrome

proc search {} {
    set driver [::selenium::ChromeDriver new] 
    $driver get "https://google.com"
    set query [$driver find_element_by_name "q"]
    $driver send_keys $query "selenium and Tcl"
    $driver send_keys $query $selenium::Key(RETURN)
    after 5000
    $driver close
    return 1
}
```

---

Now, if I try to execute the test file `add.test` by running the command `tclsh run_tests.tcl -file add.test` from terminal, it generates the following output:

```
Tests running in interp:  /usr/bin/tclsh
Tests located in:  /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Tests running in:  /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Temporary files stored in /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Test files run in separate interpreters
Running tests that match:  *
Skipping test files that match:  l.*.test
Only running test files that match:  add.test
Tests began at Thu Jul 20 12:49:22 UTC 2017
add.test

Tests ended at Thu Jul 20 12:49:22 UTC 2017
run_tests.tcl:  Total   1   Passed  1   Skipped 0   Failed  0
Sourced 1 Test Files.
```

which is perfectly fine, and is what it should be.

Whereas, if I try to execute the test file `sample.test` in a similar way, the test does not end:

```
$ tclsh run_tests.tcl -file sample.test

Tests running in interp:  /usr/bin/tclsh
Tests located in:  /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Tests running in:  /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Temporary files stored in /home/snehasish/tcl_test/tests
Test files run in separate interpreters
Running tests that match:  *
Skipping test files that match:  l.*.test
Only running test files that match:  sample.test
Tests began at Thu Jul 20 12:27:38 UTC 2017
sample.test
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 42433
Only local connections are allowed.
```

and it stops right there and as if waits for something to happen. The browser gets closed suggesting that the web-driver indeed gets closed.

Interestingly enough, when I run `sample.test` directly, it gives the expected output and ends normally:

```
$ tclsh sample.test 

Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 37381
Only local connections are allowed.
sample.test:    Total   1   Passed  1   Skipped 0   Failed  0
```

The package for Selenium Web-driver implementation I am using is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/selenium-tcl/).

Could someone please clarify why `tcltest` is not working as expected when using `runAllTests` and a web-driver script in combinaton? It would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

**PS:** I am sorry that the question became too long due to the inclusion of the contents of a number of files, but I thought this is the way in which I would be more clear in explaining my question.

Comment: runAllTests does stuff with your channels to e.g. capture output to compare it to expected output. That could be the problem, recommend looking at the source.

Comment: Try turning setting the option `-singleproc` to 1 to disable most of the tricky stuff (and decrease the isolation level of test files).

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks man! It works. However, I don't understand why it is not required in case of `add.test` in the example I gave. Also, if `runAllTests` spawns a new process for execution of each sourced test case (when `singleproc` is false), shouldn't all those child processes end automatically to return to the parent process?